# How can I change URL format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, ytdl

I am using [ytdl-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core) and it provides this URL (audio):

```
https://r2---sn-gwpa-w5py.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1612552132&ei=ZEMdYNnJDumPz7sPyrSLmAw&ip=49.36.246.217&id=o-AFQLS1cSUJ6_bXBjMOIiWk1NuIYTMUTVu4rmliPZmJCS&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=VD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-w5py%2Csn-gwpa-qxaz&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=21&initcwndbps=225000&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=nxhNYqBZK92ToigY08JRZjEF&gir=yes&clen=230633&dur=18.961&lmt=1524503096692151&mt=1612530050&fvip=2&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&n=UIc0qqVvrMQOjPVkP&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIhAObqQA5vFYy6rJ3O3J4zswofNj2NFZOrwMF05p_PgWg9AiAmnde3njBRfvPmW_2VVA0YO1aLWQl0V3STGayuqgBRKA%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgFTqy7Ng9zxhQY4GM4vP1BooPeHOf50PTikb59C67voACIGDybTTJBdLkp9lUx_-ZLdCulG_y3TH6iMhBbAn1AZR_&ratebypass=yes
```

But I want .mp3 at the end like this:

```
https://r2---sn-gwpa-w5py.googlevideo.com/13%20Beethoven%20-%20Fur%20Elise.mp3
```

I'd like `.mp3` at the end.

Is this possible? I am using JavaScript Frameworks (NodeJS at the backend and React-Native at the front end).

Comment: Welcome. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then add some code to your question.

Comment: do you ask why the URL is not end with `.mp3` or you want to output audio format as `.mp3`?

Comment: I want to know both @uingtea

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. Google decides what URLs to give their video and audio resources.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible. You cannot change the URL Google gives you. The only thing you can do is use the URL they give you.

Answer (score -1):

There is no `.mp3`, for audio it use `.m4a` or `.weba`, you need ffmpeg to convert it to `.mp3`

Answer (score -1):

With the video ID, you can use the YouTube API to lookup the title of the video. You can then grab the origin of the URL and append the track title.

If you just want the name of the video for the filename, after downloading, just set the filename to the result of `getVideoTitle`.

```js
const url = new URL('https://r2---sn-gwpa-w5py.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1612552132&ei=ZEMdYNnJDumPz7sPyrSLmAw&ip=49.36.246.217&id=o-AFQLS1cSUJ6_bXBjMOIiWk1NuIYTMUTVu4rmliPZmJCS&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=VD&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gwpa-w5py%2Csn-gwpa-qxaz&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=21&initcwndbps=225000&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=nxhNYqBZK92ToigY08JRZjEF&gir=yes&clen=230633&dur=18.961&lmt=1524503096692151&mt=1612530050&fvip=2&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&n=UIc0qqVvrMQOjPVkP&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIhAObqQA5vFYy6rJ3O3J4zswofNj2NFZOrwMF05p_PgWg9AiAmnde3njBRfvPmW_2VVA0YO1aLWQl0V3STGayuqgBRKA%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgFTqy7Ng9zxhQY4GM4vP1BooPeHOf50PTikb59C67voACIGDybTTJBdLkp9lUx_-ZLdCulG_y3TH6iMhBbAn1AZR_&ratebypass=yes');

const api = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3';
const apiKey = '<API_KEY>';

const getVideoPath = videoId => `${api}/videos?id=${videoId}&key=${apiKey}&part=snippet`;
const getVideoInfo = async (videoId) => fetch(getVideoPath(videoId));

const getVideoTitle = async (videoId) => {
  const response = await getVideoInfo(videoId);
  const info = await response.json();
  const { items: [ { snippet: { title } } ] } = info;
  return title;
};

const main = async () => {
  let title = null;
  try {
    title = await getVideoTitle('dQw4w9WgXcQ');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Please supply a valid API key!');
  }
  
  // Fallback: If API key is valid, title should not be null
  title = title || 'Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)';
  const newUrl = `${url.origin}/${encodeURIComponent(title)}.mp3`;

  console.log(newUrl);

  const query = Object.fromEntries(url.search.substring(1).split('&')
    .map(pair => pair.split('=').map(v => decodeURIComponent(v))));

  console.log(query); // Nothing of interest...
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```